# Griffon JavaFX sample app can't compile

Tags: javafx-2, griffon

I can't run the sample app from aalmiray's blog "The Griffon Trove: dialogs and JavaFX".

> [griffonc] Compiling 1 source file to
>   C:\Users\foo.griffon\1.0.1\projects\sample\classes\main Compilation
>   error: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit
>   'C:\Users\foo\sample\griffon-app\views\sample\DialogView.groovy'
>   Invalid index

Commenting the `import javafx.geometry.Insets` helps by compiling.

Groovy Version: 1.8.5 JVM: 1.6.0_24 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS: Windows 7 x64
Griffon Version: 1.0.1
JavaFX Version: 2.1 Runtime

Link is [here](http://www.jroller.com/aalmiray/entry/the_griffon_trove_dialogs_and).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you're being affected by http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-517. If this is the case then please make sure you're running latest versions of the JavaFX and GroovyFX plugins. You can quickly check if a plugin requires updates by invoking `griffon list-plugin-updates`.

You can also check http://artifacts.griffon-framework.org for updates.

Comment: `set javafx_home=c:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK`

It is necessary to build, but I always forget.

Comment: The same error message:

`Compilation error: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Users\foo\sample\griffon-app\views\sample\DialogView.groovy' Invalid index`